# Facebook Share button with facebook javascript sdk in a django template for loop

Tags: django, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having a little trouble getting this to work, I want to generate a facebook share button for each post on my website, but the way I have it set I only get a working share button for the first button instance and it only shares the very last post that is on the page, none of the other share buttons do anything.

Relevant Code

blog/post_list.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load cloudinary %}
{% block content %}
   <div id='posts'>
     {% for post in posts %}

        [...]

        <div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>
        <script>
                document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {

                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share',
                    display: 'popup',
                    href: 'http://example.com:8000{{ post.get_absolute_url          }}',
                  }, function(response){});
                }
        </script>
    {% endfor %}

    [...]

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont Ask me how this worked, but I changed

```
<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
```

to

```
 <div id="shareBtn{{ post.pk }}" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('shareBtn{{ post.pk }}').onclick = function() {
```

and it worked!